# I tried to copy everything from my word document but kept losing the content in the tables

Tags: python, copy, google-colaboratory, docx

I wanted to duplicate the SAMPLE files many times to output.docx.
I'm still on the step of copying it once. It pastes the fonts, formats, and tables, but the content in the tables are gone.
Also I wrote it with Google Colab

```
!pip install python-docx
from google.colab import files
from docx import Document

# upload SAMPLE.docx file

uploaded = files.upload()
from docx import Document
from copy import deepcopy
```

```
# open SAMPLE.docx file
sample_doc = Document('SAMPLE.docx')

# copy SAMPLE.docx to output.docx

output_doc = deepcopy(sample_doc)
output_doc.save('output.docx')
print("generated output.docx")

#read output.docx

output_doc = Document('output.docx')

# adjust font size

for table in output_doc.tables:
  for row in table.rows:
    for cell in row.cells:
      for paragraph in cell.paragraphs:
        for run in paragraph.runs:
          run.font.size = 1200

# save output.docx

output_doc.save('output.docx')
```

My final plan is as followed

1. Upload SAMPLE.DOCX and Receipt.XLSX
2. Generate TEMP.DOCX
3. loop (as many times as the rows in Receipt)

   3-1. copy SAMPLE to TEMP

   3-2. replace some words in TEMP with the data in Receipt (in the sample, some words are named as 'client_name, Price... etc.)

   3-3. copy TEMP to output

   3-4. clear TEMP
4. save OUTPUT and download

Answer (score 1):

Try below code snippet :

```
from docx import Document

def copy_word_content(source_path, destination_path):
    # Open the source document
    source_doc = Document(source_path)

    
    destination_doc = Document() # Create or open the destination document

    
    for element in source_doc.element.body:
        destination_doc.element.body.append(element) # Copy content from source to destination

    
    destination_doc.save(destination_path) # Save the destination document

# Example usage
source_document_path = "path/to/source/document.docx"
destination_document_path = "path/to/destination/document.docx"

copy_word_content(source_document_path, destination_document_path)
```

Comment: I wanted to keep the format. So I deleted the tables and just put the content raw in the document lol

Comment: I'll do it as soon as I get 15 reputation :I